# Remove brackets from list

Tags: python

I have some problems with using a list in python.
Right now, I open a .txt file with data, and read it into my python file. 
However, when I put the input from the datafile into variable `data` and print this to check if it works or not, I see a lot of extra brackets which I don't want. Right now, it looks like:

```
["['sports','pizza','other']"]
```

and I want it to have it in a way like this:

```
['sports','pizza','other']
```

Can someone help me to get this work? Reason why I want it in a format like I mentioned above, is that I want to compare the list with another list, and that does not work in the format with the `]"]`

I hope someone will help me.

Comment: Maybe this will help:    file.write(str(data)[1:-1])

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `eval` function from Python.

```
>>> a = ["['sports','pizza','other']"]
>>> eval(a[0])
['sports', 'pizza', 'other']
```

Comment: You probably rather want [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

Comment: Hmm.. Still doesn't work. I will edit the post with my code, maybe you can see then whats wrong?